# TypeScript Global Scope

Tags: typescript

I am a beginner to TypeScript. I read online that functions have a global scope by default in TypeScript.

So I have:

```
const addTwo = (num) => {return (num + 2)};
```

in file1.ts and:

```
console.log(addTwo(4));
```

in file2.ts.

Then I transpile using `tsc file1.ts file2.ts` which works, but then when I try to run them using `node talk1.js talk2.js` nothing prints out. Why does this happen and how do I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: That is not how Node works. That just executes `talk1.js` and passes the string `"talk2.js"` as an argument which is never used.

Comment: Thank you, then how do I execute both programs together?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the global scope like this you need to execute both files in the same context. In the browser you could do that just by adding two `<script>` tags, in Node however, you would need to combine the files.

It is not recommended to do this because...

- You need to keep track of the correct order in which files are added
- You can easily get name conflicts because all top-level names share the same scope
- There is no built-in support for executing files like this in Node

I would recommend reading about the different module systems (Node originally only used CommonJS but now also supports [ES modules](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html)) and using one of those. TypeScript has a [`module` option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#module) for outputting the various module formats.